How to upload product image label for all store in magento 2 when import product using csv
How to upload product image label for all store in magento 2 when import product using csv
Now we need to add multiple row for same product when want to update images label so can we update using single row for multiple store

Uploading product image labels for all stores in Magento 2 via a CSV file can indeed be streamlined, so you don't have to add multiple rows for the same product. You can achieve this by utilizing the store-specific columns and correctly structuring your CSV file. Here’s how you can do it:
image_label, small_image_label, thumbnail_label, swatch_image_label: These columns will hold the corresponding labels for the images.
Example:
sku,store_view_code,image,image_label,small_image,small_image_label,thumbnail,thumbnail_label
P001,default,/i/m/product1.jpg,Default Label,/i/m/product1.jpg,Default Small Label,/i/m/product1.jpg,Default Thumbnail Label
P001,en_us,/i/m/product1.jpg,English Label,/i/m/product1.jpg,English Small Label,/i/m/product1.jpg,English Thumbnail Label
P001,fr_fr,/i/m/product1.jpg,French Label,/i/m/product1.jpg,French Small Label,/i/m/product1.jpg,French Thumbnail Label


Fine , But i i have 7-8 store then there i need to add 7-8 row but i want to add it with single row
